# Lisp importing/loading file

Tags: file, import, lisp

Is there a way in Lisp to include code from other Lisp files?

For example, in C++ I can do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "myfile.h"
etc...
```

And in Python,

```
import antigravity
import my_module
etc...
```

Is there a Lisp equivalent?

Comment: Old question, but +1 for "import antigravity"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In addition to Rainer's answer:

If you want to load [ASDF](http://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/)-systems, use:

```
(asdf:load-system 'my-system)
```

Some Lisp implementations (CCL for example) also allow using `require` for loading ASDF systems, but that functionality is implementation dependent.  If you are using Slime, and want to load a system interactively, you can do so by typing `,l my-system` at the Slime REPL.

Another thing I wanted to point out is that, unlike in Python, using `require` or `load` in CL does not have anything to do with packages (think "namespaces").  So, if the code you are loading or requiring lives in its own package, you will either have to use its exported symbols qualified (`foo:bar`), or include those packages in the package your code lives in (`(defpackage my-package (:use cl package-you-want-to-use ...) ...)`). This does not only differ from Python `import`s, but also from C preprocessor `#include`s, the latter being mere textual inclusions.

Answer (score 18):

Use standard functions like [LOAD](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_load.htm#load) and [COMPILE-FILE](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_cmp_fi.htm#compile-file).

ANSI Common Lisp also has a function REQUIRE.

If you use as 'system' maintenance tool as an extension to Common Lisp, then you can also load or compile a whole 'system'. A 'system' is a collection of files and subsystems for which operations like load and compile are defined.